# How to accomplish read-only git branch using Gerrit access rules

Tags: gerrit

We use Gerrit 2.5-rc1) ACLs to manage access to our git projects & branches.  We try to keep the rules simple for developer groups; refs/heads/* allow Push, Create Reference, Push Merge Commit.

There is a need to mark a specific branch, call it **foo**, as read only.  I have tried adding a new rule for refs/heads/foo/*, allowing READ, but DENYing Push, Push Merge Commit, etc. (both with and without "Exclusive" tickbox ticked).  In any case, developers are still permitted to push to that branch.

Any idea how to do this without writing server hooks, etc?

Comment: What is your Gerrit version?

Comment: 2.5-rc1; updated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your Gerrit version I think the following set should do the trick:

```
refs/heads/*     ALLOW
refs/heads/foo/* BLOCK
```

Comment: thank you, I will try that. I had believed DENY and BLOCK would behave the same in this scenario.  Will update you shortly.

Comment: that seemed to do it!  Thanks!

Comment: (I also used the _Exclusive_ bit, not sure if that was necessary)